# Determinant of Kronecker Product

Tags: matrices, determinant, kronecker-product

> **Problem.** Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ be an $n\times m$ matrix. Show that $$\det(A\otimes B)=\det(B\otimes A).$$

This formula apparently holds if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, but here this assumption fails in general.

I am considering the general definition of determinant: $$\det(M)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}{(-1)^{\rm sgn(\sigma)}a_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}}.$$
We have $$\det(B\otimes A)=\det((B\otimes A)^T)=\det(B^T\otimes A^T).$$
The shape of $B^T$ is the same as $A$ and the shape of $A^T$ is the same as $B$. Intuitively, the summands in the two determinants are exactly the same, but this argument is vague and complicated. It would be better if anyone has some easier proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $m\ne n$, both determinants are zero.

Suppose $m<n$. Then $Ax=0$ has a non-trivial solution $x$. Let $y\in\mathbb F^m\setminus0$. Then $x\otimes y$ and $y\otimes x$ are nonzero but $(A\otimes B)(x\otimes y)=(Ax)\otimes(By)=0$ and likewise $(B\otimes A)(y\otimes x)=0$. Therefore $A\otimes B$ and $B\otimes A$ are singular and their determinants are zero.

Comment: This argument is really nice. Thank you!